# Uso de NgIf con varias condiciones para desplegar ng-template

Tags: angular12

tengo una estructura con cuatro ng-template, lo que deseo hacer es mostrar solamente uno de los cuatro template dependiendo el resultado del if, anteriormente si me funcionaba ya que solo tenia 2 template, pero ahora que debo utilizar 4 no se como crear el if con varias condiciones.

Las condiciones serian las siguientes:

1. Si message.mensaje.idCliente == 0 && message.tipo == 'texto'  then
   incoming_msg
2. Si message.mensaje.idCliente == 1 && message.tipo == 'texto'  then
   outgoing_msg
3. Si message.mensaje.idCliente == 0 && message.tipo == 'imagen'  then
   incoming_img_msg
4. Si message.mensaje.idCliente == 1 && message.tipo == 'imagen'  then
   outgoing_img_msg

Estas condiciones me gustaría poder hacerlas en el siguiente ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="
    message.mensaje.idCliente == 0 && message.tipo == 'texto' then incoming_msg;
    else outgoing_msg"></div>
```

Si pudieran ayudarme, muchas gracias.

```
<li class="message" *ngFor="let message of listMensajes">
    <div *ngIf="
    message.mensaje.idCliente == 0 && message.tipo == 'texto' then incoming_msg;
    else outgoing_msg"></div>
    <ng-template #incoming_msg>
        <div class="incoming_msg">
            <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #outgoing_msg>
        <div class="outgoing_msg">
            <div class="sent_msg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #incoming_img_msg>
        <div class="incoming_msg">
            <div class="incoming_msg_img">
                <img />
            </div>
            <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #outgoing_img_msg>
        <div class="outgoing_msg">
            <div class="incoming_msg_img">
                <img />
            </div>
            <div class="sent_msg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi consejo: crea un método en el componente que te diga qué opción es la que se tiene que mostrar:

```
class MYComponent {

  ...

  sectionToShow() : number {
    // aquí pones toda la lógica para calcular qué mostrar
    // y devuelves el número de la sección a mostrar: 1,2,3 o 4, por ejemplo

    // también podrías devolver un string con el nombre de la sección,
    // si te parece más legible de ese modo
  }

}
```

Y en la plantilla llamas a ese método de un modo más legible las veces que haga falta:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="sectionToShow() == 1 ">
  ...
</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="sectionToShow() == 2 ">
  ...
</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="sectionToShow() == 3 ">
  ...
</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="sectionToShow() == 4 ">
  ...
</ng-template>
```